# Excel - How to convert the combination of year, week number and day of week to calendar day?

Tags: excel, date, calendar, week-number, weekday

Have >80000 records of the type:

```
Year Week Weekday
1971 40 1
1998 25 7
2020 34 3
```

In Excel, I want to convert the data (year: 1971-2020, week: 24-44, weekday: 1-7) to the calendar day (1-365; total number of days per year varying from year to year).
Any suggestions? I find related posts, but none that solves my problem.

Comment: You need to explain how you figure the 1st day of the first week.  Where does the counting start.  Also what day is the first day of the week.  So basically what day is `2021,1,1`

Comment: Please manually work out the expected results for the sample dates. There are several different ways to determine when a week starts and what constitutes Week 1 in any given year if the start of the week is not the same day as the 1st January. So you need to tell us how you want to handle this.

Comment: Monday = Weekday 1, Sunday = Weekday 7. Taking your example (2021,1,1) is year = 2020, week = 53, weekday = 5 (Friday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside the regional specifics of what constitutes week 1 in a year where January 1 is not on the same day as the perceived start of the week, you can arrive at a running day number for each date by multiplying the week by 7 and adding the day.

```
= (Week * 7 ) + Weekday
```

Apply your regional settings of a Monday vs Sunday week start by adding or subtracting one day.

You can then even come up with a date using that number.

```
=date(Year,1, (Week * 7 ) + Weekday)
```

This will use the first day of January as the first week, though. If that doesn't suit, you'll need to adjust by working out what week 1 means in any one year.

**Edit:**

Here is a table with your sample data:

[image]

The formula for **year day** is

```
=[@Week]*7
```

The formula for **adjust year start is**

```
=WEEKDAY(DATE([@Year],1,1))
```

The formula for the final **date** is

```
=DATE([@Year],1,[@[year day]])-[@[adjust year start]]
```

You can see that year 2020, week 53, day 5 is shown as 1st January 2021, so that matches up. You can move the **adjust year start** calculation into the **year day** column, of course.

Comment: I added a formula with your sample data. Does that do what you need?

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for this elegant and simple solution! Will adjust by week 1 for the respective years.